# Android Push Notification with Image Not Expanding Automatically

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

Currently we are facing issue regarding Android Push Notification Big Image. We have Custom Layout to show Push Notification with Big Image. Currently what we facing issue is that on Certain Devices Like (Xiaomi and Samsung), The Push Notification with Image not Expand Automatically while on all other devices it is Auto Expanding. My Question, How we can fix it ?

Below is my Code which i'm using for this purpose.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap)); /*Notification with Image*/
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX); //PRIORITY_HIGH);
            builder.setContentIntent(clickPendingIntent);
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);

            builder.setContent(remoteViews);

            // Settings
            long[] pattern = {500, 500, 500, 500, 500};
            builder.setVibrate(pattern);

            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            builder.setSound(alarmSound);

            Notification notification = builder.build();
            notification.bigContentView = remoteViews;
```

Above Code is not complete but main Properties are there.So need community people help to guide on the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: check whether notification contents is shown or hidden in the settings.

Comment: @ManojFrekzz i have already check the device Setting. But all OK.
That's why i mentioned Majority of the Device Auto Expanding the PUSH Notification Image just Xiaomi Note 3 and Samsung 7 Edge is not auto Expanding. we need to expand it Manually.

Comment: usually this occurs, when we forgot to add the high priority. But in this case you already have added it, so i thought it occurs because of the notification settings issue. Whether any runtime permissions missing?